# Why does Eclipse keep insisting that my answer needs to be a double even though I've casted it as a double?

Tags: java

Here's my code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pey4e.png)

I've tried casting it, but it doesn't work. I've spent an entire 2 hours trying to make sense of this, but I can't. For context, I've been assigned to make a math library but with conditionals, so that's why I'm rounding to 2 decimals.

Code:

```java
public static double round2 (double m) {
    if (m < 0) {
        double b=  (m*-1);
        double h = b * 1000;
        double v= h+ 5;
        double num = (int) v /10;
        double ans =(double) (num/100)*-1;
        return  (double) ans;
    }else if (m > 0){
        double n = m * 1000;
        double f= n+ 5;
        double num2 = (int) f/10;
        double ans2 = (double) num2/100;
        return  (double) ans2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is that both the `if` and the `else if` conditions may be false, in which case the method does not return a value. Either change `else if` to `else` or add an `else` block. Your code does not handle the case where `m` is zero.

Answer (score 1):

First, add missing return statement for the case when m is equal to 0:
If m is equal to 0, the code doesn't return any value, which will result in a compilation error. You should add a return statement for this case.

Only pass the valid values while invoking the function

```
public static double round2(double m) {
        double ans = 0;
        if(m<0) {
          //your code goes here
             ans= {result};
           
        }else if(m>0) {
          //your code goes here
             ans= {result};
            
        }else {
           ans= {result};
             }
        return ans;
    }
```